# Best way to avoid merge nulls

Tags: python, pandas, merge, null

Let's say I have those 2 pandas dataframes.

```
In [3]: df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id':[None,20,None,40,50],'value':[1,2,3,4,5]})
In [4]: df2 = pd.DataFrame({'index':[None,20,None], 'value':[1,2,3]})

In [7]: df1
Out[7]:      id  value
        0   NaN      1
        1  20.0      2
        2   NaN      3
        3  40.0      4
        4  50.0      5

In [8]: df2
Out[8]:    index  value
        0    NaN      1
        1   20.0      2
        2    NaN      3
```

When I'm merging those dataframes (based on the id and index columns) - the result include rows that the id and index have missing values.

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2, left_on='id', right_on = 'index', how='inner')

In [9]: df3
Out[9]:      id  value_x  index  value_y
        0   NaN        1    NaN        1
        1   NaN        1    NaN        3
        2   NaN        3    NaN        1
        3   NaN        3    NaN        3
        4  20.0        2   20.0        2
```

that's what I tried but I guess it's not the best solution:

I replaced all the missing values with some value in one dataframe column,
and the same in the second dataframe but with another value - the purpose is that the condition will return False and the rows will not be in the result.

```
In [14]: df1_fill = df1.fillna({'id':'NONE1'})
In [13]: df2_fill = df2.fillna({'index':'NONE2'})

In [15]: df1_fill
Out[15]:       id  value
         0  NONE1      1
         1     20      2
         2  NONE1      3
         3     40      4
         4     50      5

In [16]: df2_fill
Out[16]:    index  value
         0  NONE2      1
         1     20      2
         2  NONE2      3
```

What is the best solution for that issue?

Also, in the example - the daya type of the join columns is numeric, but it can be another type like text or date...

**EDIT:**

So, with the solutions here I can use dropna function to drop the rows with the missing values before the join - but this is good with inner join that I don't want those rows at all.

What about a left join or full join?

Let's say I have those 2 dataframes I've used before - df1, df2.

So for inner and left join I realy can use the dropna function:

```
In [61]: df_inner = df1.dropna(subset=['id']).merge(df2.dropna(subset=['index']), left_on='id', right_on = 'index', how='inner')
In [62]: df_inner

Out[62]:      id  value_x  index  value_y
         0  20.0        2   20.0        6

In [63]: df_left = df1.merge(df2.dropna(subset=['index']), left_on='id', right_on = 'index', how='left')
In [64]: df_left

Out[64]:      id  value_x  index  value_y
         0   NaN        1    NaN      NaN
         1  20.0        2   20.0      6.0
         2   NaN        3    NaN      NaN
         3  40.0        4    NaN      NaN
         4  50.0        5    NaN      NaN

In [65]: df_full = df1.merge(df2, left_on='id', right_on = 'index', how='outer')
In [66]: df_full

Out[66]:      id  value_x  index  value_y
         0   NaN        1    NaN      5.0
         1   NaN        1    NaN      7.0
         2   NaN        3    NaN      5.0
         3   NaN        3    NaN      7.0
         4  20.0        2   20.0      6.0
         5  40.0        4    NaN      NaN
         6  50.0        5    NaN      NaN
```

In the left I droped the missing-values-rows from the "right" dataframe and then I used merge.

It was ok because in left join you know that If the condition returns false you have null in the right-source columns - so it's not matter if the rows realy exists or they jusr return false.

But for full join - I need all the rows from the 2 sources both...

I cant use dropna because it will drop me rows that I need and if I don't use it - I get wrong result.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you want the output be like?

Answer (score 1):

Why not to do something like this:

```
pd.merge(df1.dropna(subset=['id']), df2.dropna(subset=['index']), 
                                    left_on='id',right_on='index', how='inner')
```

Output:

```
id  value_x index   value_y
0   20.0    2   20.0    2
```

Answer (score 1):

If you dont want nan values then you can drop the nan values i.e

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2, left_on='id', right_on = 'index', how='inner').dropna()
```

or

```
df3 = df1.dropna().merge(df2.dropna(), left_on='id', right_on = 'index', how='inner')
```

Output:

```
     id  value_x  index  value_y
0  20.0        2   20.0        2
```

For outer merge drop after merging ie.

```
df_full = df1.merge(df2, left_on='id', right_on = 'index', how='outer').dropna(subset = ['id'])
```

Output:

```
     id  value_x  index  value_y
4  20.0        2   20.0      2.0
5  40.0        4    NaN      NaN
6  50.0        5    NaN      NaN
```

Comment: OK, what about left\full join?

Comment: If you add the expected output. It would helpful to provide better solution.

Comment: Thanks, but there is no the expected result of full-join:
I expected 7 rows (4 "unique" rows from df1, 2 "unique" rows from df2, and only 1 common rows - that returns true for the condition)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are doing an 'inner' join, what you could do is drop the rows in df1 where the id column is NaN before you merge.

```
df1_nonan = df1.dropna(subset = ['id'])
df3 = df1_nonan.merge(df2, left_on='id', right_on = 'index', how='inner')
```